# how to change NA-s to empty cells in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a data frame with varying number of columns (depending on the year I have fewer or more data points). Originally this is a cross-sectional time series long dataset rather than a wide dataset but I need to pull out a vector for each year from it (and I would like to create country tables).

At the moment R puts `NA`s at the end of the rows if I have fewer data points (which means that some of the end columns have NA-s).

However I would like to use each row as an input vector in a Python code that does not like `NA`s. So I would like to replace the `NA`s with empty cells. It would be ideal to have different length vectors. Replacing the `NA`s with zeros does not work either since I would like to keep track of the different row sizes for different years. I have found answers for characters but I have numbers, any help would be appreciated. 
The goal is to write a table or csv file without the NA-s, as I would like to pass each row in a python code.
Thank you!

```
 mat1 <- matrix(c(3,0, 1, 13, NA, NA,NA, 3, 0, 1, 13, 
                  NA, NA, NA, 3, 0 ,1 ,16, NA, NA, NA,
                  3,0, 1, 16, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 134, 33, 39, 1, 14,    
                  0,0, 134, 33, 39, 1, 14),7,6)
print(t(mat1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    3    0    1   13   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]    3    0    1   13   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]    3    0    1   16   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]    3    0    1   16   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]    0    0  134   33   39    1   14
 [6,]    0    0  134   33   39    1   14
```

As a data.frame:

```
> print(as.data.frame(t(mat1)))
 >    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
 > 1  3  0   1 13 NA NA NA
 > 2  3  0   1 13 NA NA NA
 > 3  3  0   1 16 NA NA NA
 > 4  3  0   1 16 NA NA NA
 > 5  0  0 134 33 39  1 14
 > 6  0  0 134 33 39  1 14
```

Comment: A matrix is rectangular by definition. If you have non-rectangular data, use a `list` instead. You can use `na.omit` to get rid of the missing values for any row/column you want.

Comment: exactly it is a data frame not a matrix. I use a python code with the csv that I  write and at the end so I would like to have the same structure to append it to my dataset. So I would like to preserve the varying number of columns. for efficiency I would like to create tables for each country and pass the table through python. so I cannot really use the list format. thank you for your answer!

Comment: I have to say that it would have been **really** useful for you to have added this context (you're passing information to Python via a CSV file) in the original question.  I think @zx8754's comment solves your problem, mine might be irrelevant (since I didn't have enough information about your approach to give the best answer) :-(

Comment: I'm happy to take input from the OP and others as to whether I should delete my answer ...

Comment: I am sorry this is my first post and I am editing as your feedback comes in. Thank you for the helpful comments!

Comment: @BenBolker FWIW, I hope you won't delete the answer. This little rant might be a topic for meta: There are many standard comments for novice users on how to ask questions, like the need to post an MWE and the (in)famous "what did you try". But I'm not sure if there is any official recommendation that it is *not* OK to change the question with edits. IMO edits should only clarify the question. But lately I've seen quite often what I like to call "moving the target". Once a valid answer is posted, the post is edited to include further questions, sometimes only loosely related to the original one

Comment: Thank you. I think I was just clarifying the question, I did not ask anything new. As a newbie I am not sure if this is my place but I sort of disagree. If I reposted the entire question just to clarify it, especially several times it would have been quite annoying I suppose and the original question probably would not have had any meaning or function. I understand that some of the people who answered could not give me the right answer because I could not formulate the question correctly  (I am really sorry) but it would have not been much better with 3 separate questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how you're passing the rows to Python code, there are a variety of ways of handling this, but none of them correspond to "emptying cells" - an `NA` value is already (arguably) the best/most sensible way to code an empty cell in a rectangular array in R.

```
 mat1 <- matrix(c(3,0, 1, 13, NA, NA,NA, 3, 0, 1, 13, 
              NA, NA, NA, 3, 0 ,1 ,16, NA, NA, NA,
              3,0, 1, 16, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 134, 33, 39, 1, 14,    
              0,0, 134, 33, 39, 1, 14),nrow=7,ncol=6)
 mat2 <- t(mat1)  ## see below
 ## Your text description says that `NA` values come at the end
 ## of *rows*, but your  matrix has `NA` values at the end of 
 ## *columns*, so I've transposed the matrix.
```

Since your stated is goal is to

> write a table or csv file without the NA-s

the correct answer (as hinted at by a now-deleted comment) is to use `write.csv(...,na="")`: from `?write.csv`,

> na: the string to use for missing values in the data.

More generally, if you wanted to pass rows to Python one at a time, you could use one of the following strategies:

- use `na.omit()` to strip out `NA` values:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mat2))
    call_my_python_code(na.omit(mat2[i,]))
```

or

```
apply(mat2,1,function(x) call_my_python_code(na.omit(x))
```

- store the data as a list, either from the very beginning or by splitting it into a list (you still have to get rid of the `NA` values):

```
my_list <- split(mat2,row(mat2))
my_list <- lapply(my_list,na.omit)
lapply(my_list,call_my_python_code)
```

- store the data in long format and use `plyr` or `dplyr` tools to operate on chunks ...

```
library(reshape2)
mat3 <- na.omit(melt(mat2))
mat3[mat3$Var1==1,]  ## row 1
library(plyr)
dlply(mat3,"Var1",function(x) call_my_python_code(x$value))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I need to brush up on my python skills I feel. Maybe I did more work than i had to with restructuring my data. I cannot believe I did not think about the na="" solution! Thank you!